# Frequent short-term student visa - UK/US citizen

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, us-citizens, borders, dual-nationality

I’m 20 years old, a US citizen but living in Jordan. I graduated from high school two years ago. I took one short course with a short course visa then one full-time 1-year foundation course with a tier 4 then another 2 two short courses with short course visa, each was three months.

The last time I was at the border they held me for quite a while and everything was complicated because they saw I’ve been taking many successful visits with student visas. They let me in the UK and the officer said that I was so lucky and I won’t be ever able to take another student visa. I’ve been taking all these courses because my aim is to get into Saint Martins, which has a 1% acceptance rate and I want to get my degree there, so I’ve been preparing my portfolio with these short courses.

Now I left the UK and I’m back in Jordan for a year. I want to take another short course in the UK. I don’t know what to do since the officer told me last time that I won’t be able to get another student visa again. I have a Jordanian passport: can I apply to the student visa with my Jordanian passport rather than go with my US passport? Will they know that it’s in my record that I’m not allowed to take another short-term course again? Will they cause a fuss like last time?

Comment: They will almost certainly be able to match you or your Jordanian passport to your existing immigration history.  They have your name, date and place of birth, and, if I'm not mistaken, your fingerprints.

Comment: The vote to close in favor of expatriates is inappropriate since this question concerns *short-term* studies; Expatriates is for "moving for extended periods of time (studies or employment, among others)."

Comment: How long is this 'short course'? You don't need a visa with your US passport if the course is less than 6 months. https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/study/six_months_or_less

Comment: It’s 3 months but thats the  thing Sam . They saw that I’ve been coming and going for short courses all the time and they gave me a red flag called my university ... Told me that they wrote in my record that it’s the last short term study visa they’ll give me and they won’t ever give me another one again . The officer next to the officer who was dealing with me told me that I came to the toughest officer .

Answer (score 4):

Your questions are...

> [C]an I apply to the [short-term study] visa with my Jordanian passport rather than go with my US passport?

To answer this, we can turn to [Paragraph 320, Subparagraph 7D-11](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal), which says, in part (emphasis mine):

> ...and there are other aggravating circumstances, such as absconding, not meeting temporary admission/reporting restrictions or bail conditions, using an assumed identity or **multiple identities, switching nationality**, making frivolous applications or not complying with the re-documentation process.

They will not prosecute because you are a ‘small fry.’ They may not even impose a ban; however, they are likely to put a stop flag on both passports and ask both countries to keep them advised of new identities, new passports, and so on. It means they consider this to be an 'aggravating circumstance' and it's something they will not forget for a long time (if you are caught out that is). Note that if your school finds out, they will be obliged to report you to UKVI.

> Will they know that it’s in my record that I’m not allowed to take another sts again?

No, there is nothing in your record. From what you wrote, the IO gave you a casual warning. There was no paperwork and you were not removed. There is nothing in your narrative to indicate that a ban (or any other restriction) was imposed.

> Will they cause a fuss like last time?

We are not prophets, but I suspect the next time with your US passport will result in a removal, and with your Jordanian passport then Paragraph 320 is engaged.

---

Note that it is fine to for people to come and go on different passports. It is a normal event in a multinational society as we're in. You, however, would be using different passports to evade immigration control and this would be pretty clear to a caseworker who examined both passports. An IO would most likely be able to figure it out with a single passport, but that's merely supposition based on your narrative here.

Comment: The material you quote from subparagraph 11 concerns those who have previously overstayed, breached a condition attached to leave, been an illegal entrant, or used deception in an application.  None of those applies here.